# Uploading files without form?

Tags: php, uploading, image-upload

I wanna make my own little renderfarm-backend building on php and mysql. I have a huge plan for doing everything but there is one problem. How can I upload an image without a form?

Answer (score 1):

Three alternatives:

1. you make exactly the POST request a browser would do when submitting an upload form, you do not need the form for that. It is a simple http POST. You can find countless examples for that here on SO or on google.
2. take a look at webdav, an http extension that allows flexible file access via http. Might make sense if you want to integrate your uploading into something like a local file manager or the like.
3. you use a file centered protocol for uploading, so implement the upload separate from the php stuff. sftp comes to mind here, but obviously you need to setup a separate server for that and map the file system locations as required. Also you have to take care of the file permissions.

Comment: So it is not possible to tell my phpscript via get, which file it should upload?

Comment: Sorry, but that question is confusing. Certainly you can make a http GET request to some PHP file. But typically that file will be server side, so how should that file _upload_ something from your client to the server? You might define a setup where you use a GET request to tell some php script to _download_ a file from some other server, maybe a public http server offering some public resources. But that would be the other way around. Or is your setup such that you really want to _upload_ files from your php scripts to some _other_ server? Then say so!